# SAVE groups clustering to out of r

Tags: r

I wrote the follow code to clustering data :

```
clusrer.data <- function(data,n) {
  miRNA.exp.cluster <- scale(t(miRNA.exp))
  k.means.fit <- kmeans(miRNA.exp.cluster,n)
  #i try to save the results of k-means cluster by this code : 
  k.means.fit <- as.data.frame(k.means.fit)
  write.csv(k.means.fit, file="k-meanReslut.csv")
  #x<-k.means.fit$clusters
  #write.csv(x, file="k-meanReslut.csv")
}
```

but I can not save the clusters to outside of (clusters) (8, 6, 7, 20, 18), I want to save  each cluster separated (with columns  and rows) in txt file or CSV.

Comment: Please rethink about how you're asking. We don't have access to your data. Paint us a picture of what we're after and what the expected result should look like.

Comment: This is not enough. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to provide an example.

Comment: i have done the clustering by k-means , the result 5 Clusters. after Clustering . i want to save the each cluster in txt or CSV file . every Cluster should contain names of columns and names of rows and the data in cluster.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not making myself clear. Provide us with an example that will demonstrate your problem or at least provide enough information about the data that gives us a fighting chance of what is going on. Also, it's not entirely clear what the result is suppose to look like. Please show that, too.

Comment: this is example by iris data ,          ##########                                                   http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/kmeans-clustering                                          ############                                                                                                      after clustering  i want to save the clusters in txt file or csv file, every Cluster should contain names of columns and names of rows and the data in cluster

Comment: Please revisit my comments and answer. Until you address these points, there's really no point in debating further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach of splitting the original dataset according to cluster and saving that chunk to a file. I added cluster assignment to the original dataset for easier visual check. Example is partly taken from `?kmeans`. Feel free to adapt the way files are written, as well as the way file name is created.

```
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
(cl <- kmeans(x, 2))

x <- cbind(x, cluster = cl$cluster)

by(x, INDICES = cl$cluster, FUN = function(sp) {
  write.table(sp, file = paste0("file", unique(sp$cluster), ".txt"),
              row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
})
```